# Fill custom attribute product during checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, architecture

Imagine this situation: in some situation the user, (in the cart view) are able to buy  a special discount card, this card need the username, lastname and birthday.

In my configuration I have a product "discount card" with a special attribute set for handling the input data (name lastname birthday).

Now I need to understand how to proceed with situation or if another better situation exist. One alternative is to create each time a virtual product with this data filled but sound awful.

Please if someone can give an hint I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

you can use the custom options feature.
For your product add 3 custom options (required or not, your choice). one for each field you need the customer to fill in.